# What is the command to add newline linebreak in \sum \prod?

Tags: line-breaking, amsmath

I am sure this question or similar has been asked but I cannot find it by searching so adding it to make it more accessible: what is the command/environment to add newline linebreak in \sum \prod so the expression is on two rows instead of one line hard to read?

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\begin{document}

$$\sum^{N_{cut}}_{i=1,\newline e_1\in C_i,e_2\not\in C_i} \prod_{j\in C_i} p_j-\sum^{N_{cut}}_{i=1,e_2\in C_i,e_1\not\in C_i} \prod_{j\in C_i} p_j\geq 0$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: By the way, don't use `$$...$$` in LaTeX documents. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/3954

Comment: `\[ \sum_{\substack{x<0\\ y>7}}^{8} \]`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `$$ … $$` for display equations: this is a plain tex syntax, and it can give inconsistent vertical spacing. Use `\[ … \]` instead.

The command you're looking for is `\substack` from `amsmath`. I replaced amsmath with `mathtools`, an extension of the latter. It has, among many features, commands for not taking into account the width of the indices in sums, products and the like: `\mathclap` and, more globally, `\smashoperator`. I show how to use both. Also, don't write `\N_{cut}`: the word ‘cut’ is considered by latex as the product of three variables, typed in italics and spaced accordingly. The `\text` command results in the correct typing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\[ \smashoperator{\sum^{N_\text{cut}}_{\substack{i=1,\\ e_1\in C_i,\\e_2\notin C_i}}} \prod_{j\in C_i} p_j-\sum^{N_\text{cut}}_{\substack{i=1,\\\mathclap{e_2\in C_i,}\\\mathclap{e_1\notin C_i}}} \prod_{j\in C_i} p_j\geq 0\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{multline}
\sum^{N_{cut}}_{i=1,\newline e_1\in C_i,e_2\not\in C_i} \prod_{j\in C_i} p_j
\\
-\sum^{N_{cut}}_{i=1,e_2\in C_i,e_1\not\in C_i} \prod_{j\in C_i} p_j\geq 0
\end{multline}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP's asking for line breaks inside the subscripts (as in the question I linked in comments for duplicate) not for multiple line equations.

Comment: That's not the way I read the question.  It's ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Bernard is correct about substack. I provide here MWE so easy to get things working also in the future when forgetting this again.

[image]

```
\begin{equation}
\sum^{N_{cut}}_
{
    \substack{
    i=1
    \\
    e_1\in C_i,e_2\not\in C_i
    }
} 
\prod_{j\in C_i}p_j
-
\sum^{N_{cut}}_
{
    \substack{
    i=1
    \\
    e_2\in C_i,e_1\not\in C_i}  
    }
\prod_{j\in C_i}p_j
\geq 0
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature is offered by the `amsmath` package.
If you run `texdoc amsmath` you will get a pdf with the manual.
In the index you will find Section 7 "Integrals and Sums" and the first subsection is "Multiline subscripts".
Following the instructions you get

```
\[
  \sum^{N_{cut}}_{\substack{i=1,\\ e_1\in C_i,e_2\not\in C_i}}
  \prod_{j\in C_i} p_j-\sum^{N_{cut}}_{i=1,e_2\in C_i,e_1\not\in C_i}
  \prod_{j\in C_i} p_j\geq 0
\]
```

that is to say, you use `\substack` to indicate that you want a multiline subscript and `\\` to indicate where to break the line in its argument.